# How to release Maven project using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

When I am trying to release a Maven project using Jenkins, I am getting an error like this:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project maven-plugin: You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the project (or one of its submodules) is not a SNAPSHOT project, i.e. it's version is not `[version]-SNAPSHOT` but only `[version]`.

You cannot release a project that is not a SNAPSHOT project so you need to change the version of your `pom.xml` to include `-SNAPSHOT`.